# Do "direct object を" and "directional を" occupy the same slot?

Tags: grammar, particle-を

*A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar* (ADoBJG) lists more than one を particle.  In particular:

- On page 347, it lists **o**<sup>1</sup>, *a particle which marks a direct object*.
- On page 349, it lists **o**<sup>2</sup>, *a particle which indicates a space in / on / across / through / along which s.o. or s.t. moves*.

The second particle, which I'll call ***directional を***, appears to be used quite differently from the ***direct object を***.  According to ADoBJG, the directional を is used only with verbs of motion, which I think are generally intransitive.  For example, directional を appears in the phrase `空を飛ぶ`, combining the intransitive verb of motion `飛ぶ` with an を-marked noun.

Since it's listed as a separate particle in ADoBJG, and since it behaves so differently, and since it appears in different contexts from the other を, I've always thought of directional を as a *separate particle* which happens to be *written and pronounced the same way*.  However, in 国語辞典s such as [大辞林 and 大辞泉](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%92), both usages are listed under the same entry.  So I'm wondering how independent the two really are.

It seems to me that, because directional を appears with intransitive verbs, and because direct object を appears with transitive verbs, the two occupy separate syntactic slots.  That makes me wonder if it's possible to take a construction such as 空を飛ぶ, which uses the directional を, and turn it into a transitive construction which *also* takes the direct object を, such as `◯◯を空を飛ばす`.

My thought is this: if they don't really occupy different slots, then this is ungrammatical because of the *double-o constraint*, which says that a single verb phrase may have no more than one を-marked noun phrase.  But if they *do* occupy different slots, and they're really different particles, then you should be able to create a single verb phrase containing both.

I'm not sure my `◯◯を空を飛ばす` example is very good.  (It's supposed to mean *"send ◯◯ flying through the air"*.)  But if it's possible to create a grammatical example combining both directional を and direct object を, I would like to know, regardless of whether my particular example is very good.

**Is it possible to create such a construction?**

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but keep in mind that even if that construction isn't possible, that isn't necessarily proof that the two をs are the same; it could very easily be the case that the semantic restriction on the direct object marker 'leaked' backwards into a syntactic one on を in general.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thanks, that's a good point.  I think what I'm most interested in here is whether the construction is possible.

Comment: FWIW, `ボールを空を飛ばす` sounds fine to me; even like a description for a homerun or something.

Comment: ボールを空を飛ばす does not make any sense...  飛ばす does not take the same を as 飛ぶ...

Comment: I forgot to add that it should be ボールを空へ飛ばす.

Comment: If you don't like that example that you can choose a different one that gets the same effect. Like 人を道を歩かせる, which also doesn't *feel* wrong to me, but I'm not a native so my intuition may not be worth much.

Comment: To be honest, downvotes on questions like this one are why I don't take downvotes too seriously anymore.  I did my best to research the question and ask it clearly, and I think the question makes sense.  And unfortunately, without a comment explaining the downvote I may never know what was perceived as being wrong with this question, so if there *is* something wrong I can't learn from it to write better questions in the future.

Comment: +1 for such a creative and interesting question!  Unfortunately I cannot come up with definitive "no" and back it up.  All I can say is that it sounds so very strange to have two を lined up like that ;)

Comment: @ssb:  That, too sounds strange.  As has been pointed out in the answers, 人に道を歩かせる sounds much better.

Comment: Yeah I had a slight brain fart there in forgetting that it should be 人に歩かせる and not を

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I posed this question to a native Japanese speaker. Her response was that even though to an English speaker the `を` in

> ボールを投げる

and the `を` in

> 道を歩く

may seem different, to a Japanese speaker they are exactly the same. In both cases, `を` marks the direct object, not in some vague grammatical sense of the term, but in the very tangible sense that the object is *directly acted upon* by the subject.

For a Japanese speaker, the `道` in

> 道を歩く

is not a piece of background scenery that the subject of the sentence simply floats past on their way from point A to point B; rather, it is tread on, pushed, even kicked, by the subject's feet.

For an English speaker, this is a rather alien concept, but for a Japanese speaker, to walk along a road is to *act on* the road. `を` serves one function: marking the direct object.

---

**Update:** Searching the web, I find [results](http://questionbox.jp.msn.com/qa1532140.html) that [contradict](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1268761667) my original answer. 「投げる」 is a transitive verb (他動詞) while 「歩く」 is intransitive (自動詞), *even when used with 「を」* (as an aside, this is unlike the verb "walk" in English, which can be either transitive or intransitive). According to these sources, when 「を」 is used with a 自動詞, it does *not* mark the direct object, as a 自動詞 cannot take a direct object.

I found an entire [100-page paper on the subject of 「を+自動詞」](http://ir.lib.pccu.edu.tw/retrieve/48248/3664_gsweb.pdf) which looks fascinating, but I have yet to read. Today I also intend to ask the opinion of two more native speakers, both Japanese teachers.

Finally, the Japanese [wiktionary page](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%92) on `を` **directly answers your question**:

> 用法
>   一つの単文の中で、をは一つしか使われない。従って目的語と経路のをは共存できない。
>   馬（うま）を通（とお）す。
>   門（もん）を通す。
>   *馬を門を通す。 (誤り)

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the idea of a road walked on being treated like that, at least not when it comes to 歩く. If that were really the way that Japanese people interpreted it then I can't help but feel that 歩く would be treated as a transitive verb and there would be no ambiguity with regard to how を functions

Comment: There clearly *is* a difference, it's true.  I appreciate this answer and may accept it, but I'm still going to wait a bit to see if anyone else has something to add.

Comment: I condone this answer because it shows that syntax can feed back onto the interpretation. Also, even Englishmen can "walk the walk".

Comment: @ssb, @snailboat I encourage you to ask a native speaker. My source didn't even understand the question the first few times I asked because she didn't see the difference in how を functions in the two example sentences I gave. `道を歩く` is the most tangible example we discussed, but she said the same thing about others like `空を飛ぶ`. But of course, that is only *one* person's opinion, and she is not a linguist.

Comment: @snailboat Let me add that this was an excellent question. I was really surprised to hear the response I got, and now that my curiosity has been piqued I intend to ask several other native speakers what they think.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The person I just asked told me that they do feel different. Would make an interesting survey...

Comment: Another example in English where walk takes a d.o. would be "walk the plank"...

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot When I said "there clearly is a difference", I don't mean to say that you're wrong and they're two different particles.  But there is a difference in how the two senses of を are used; one use appears mainly with transitive verbs, and the other with intransitive verbs of motion.  (This makes me question how *intransitive* is defined, though.  *Walk* is usually considered transitive in *walk the plank*...)

Answer (score 6):

First, I agree with the answer given by [ThisSuitIsBlackNot](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/3794/thissuitisblacknot) in that people do not distinguish between the two uses of を.

Now back to the original question:

> Is it possible to create such a construction?

No.

道を走る is OK. 人を走らせる is OK. 人を道を走らせる is not OK, because it is not clear who is being compelled to run.

Both 人に道を走らせる and 道で人を走らせる make sense though.