# 2 Translation Questions ( な and 所), and a Question about を vs. に when using おじぎしてまわる

Tags: translation

> 「そこで、名前を変えるには、改名の披露というものをしないといけない。いいか。**それはな**、首へ市蔵と書いたふだをぶらさげて、私は以来市蔵と申しますと、口上を云って、**みんなの所をおじぎして**まわるのだ。」

I have three questions about the bold characters.

1. I assume that **それはな** = **それ** + **は** + **な**, *NOT* **それ** + **はな**. So is **な** here being used similarly to its role as a sentence-ending particle? e.g. "If that is agreeable,"
2. What does **みんなの所** mean in this context? I took it mean "each person's place/where each person is".
3. Why is **おじぎして** using **を** and not **に**?
    Wouldn't "*bowing towards each person's place*" make more sense than "*bowing to each person's place*" since the subject (presumably) isn't literally bowing to the *place*, but the person who exists there?
   **EDIT: In answer to #3, be sure to read the comments and Chocolate's linked discussions.**

As always, I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. それはな / それはね

The な and ね usages here are softeners used for redundant confirmation in casual speech, equivalent to the colloquial 'ya know' in English.

> 2. みんなの所

To everyone's house, place of business, etc.

> 3. Why is おじぎして using を and not に?

It is not. The を is modifying まわる. It could be phrased みんなの所を回って(人に）おじぎする。Basically it is saying that your would need to visit everybody to 'pay your respects' and inform them of your new name.

Comment: Are you sure を is modifying まわる? According to Jisho, まわる is an intransitive verb and according to Tae Kim, intransitive verbs "_cannot_ take a direct object (the 「を」 particle)." Jisho: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BE%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8B Tae Kim: http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/transtype

Comment: According to Kotonoha, there are a few example sentences using this phrasing: 「いろいろな場所を回るから大変そうです。」「いろんなさくらの名 所を回る のに大忙し！」. In this usage it takes on transitive function, as opposed to 地球がまわる, etc.  'Making the rounds' is a transitive action.

Comment: @Hyper As for を+intransitive verb, or the spacious を, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3243/9831  / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12799 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6869/9831

Comment: After reading those, I understand the final sentence as (roughly) "moving _through_ the cycle" of visiting everyone's house and bowing. (I guess it's implied that you're bowing to the homeowners). Thank you for the links.