# を usage over から and で in example sentences related to movement

Tags: grammar, particle-を, particle-で, particle-から

While reading a grammar book, I learned を may mark a.) a starting point of where a movement occurs,  or b.) mark a location where a movement occurs. Examples:

> a1.) 車｛くるま｝**を**降りました｛おりました｝。(He) got out of the car.
>
> b1.) 危ない｛あぶない｝なあ！歩道{ほどう｝**を**走る｛はしる｝なよ！(That's) dangerous! Don't ride on the sidewalk!

However, other particles serve similar functions, and I don't quite understand the differences in usage. For example,

> a2.) 車**から**降りました。
>
> b2.) 危ないなあ！歩道**で**走るなよ！

Why would someone used を in the first sentence instead of から? Why would someone use を in the second sentence instead of で? How do the meanings in these individual sentences change between one choice over the other? When to use を in sentences like these and when to use different particles?

Comment: These might be of your interest, too: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12799/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12734/9831