Natives opinion on the particle を　and its (multi?)usage
Recently the を　particle has been bugging me a lot, the normal usage is that it marks the object of a transitive verb(他動詞), that I know. But there’s two を that I’m not sure if they’re the same を or completely different ones and I want natives to help me out one this one.
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12871/65948
In this response, someone asked a Japanese person is there a difference between the を in ボールを投げる　and 道を歩く and the native’s response is that they mean the exact same thing which I’m just confuse. I know 他動詞 and 自動詞 isn’t the exact same as English’s transitive and intransitive but what’s the difference?
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44535/65948
This maybe be an answer but I’m not quite sure if it’s true. From my point of view, the を particle is something you have to ACT on, not DO on. Throwing a ball could both be me acting on the ball, meaning I’m actually touching the thing, and doing the actual verb on it, that being throwing. I feel like the を particle is you ACTING on something, not exactly doing the verb to it. That’s the only reason as to why を is perceived the same thing in both sentences. 道を歩く is I’m acting on road, but I’m not doing the verb to it. Im acting on it because there’s physically no other why for me to get over the road without stepping on the road itself but not exactly me doing the walk to the road, like I’m not “I do the walk road”, but if that’s the case then it kinda is the same with で and I don’t know what’s the difference between is.
And the second one is the verb 伴う, usually the verb is attached with the に particle, making it that you accompany someone but for some reason attaching を to it makes it passive for some weird reason, you being accompanied by someone. This really makes no sense cause what about the actual passive version of 伴う? The を particle literally makes the passive conjugation useless in this case.
I want natives to help me out on this one, do you guys perceive these three を the same one を or are they three different ones to begin with. That’s without mentioning the fact that dictionary goo compares it to から which opens up a whole can of worms. Really を just seems like it can be anything at this point. If possible, please give a metaphor for this answer cause I want to see why you guys actually perceive it as.

本を見た.  I haven't done anything to the book.  I've merely perceived it, not acted upon it.

Regarding 道を歩く, does the English "walk the plank" confuse you?

I am a native Japanese speaker myself, but you need to keep in mind that an average native Japanese speaker is terribly bad at explaining the grammar of their own language. They don't know there are several types of verb conjugation until they learn it in middle school, and they will never notice that 行く is an irregular verb in their lifetime. Naturally, they cannot explain the difference between が and は. While they have an intuitive sense of whether a certain sentence is natural or unnatural, they cannot explain why.
Regarding your question, ordinary native speakers haven't even heard of Japanese transitive and intransitive verbs in the first place, so it's only natural that they cannot sense the difference of を between ボールを投げる and 道を歩く. We can say these phrases from age 2 or 3, but we never explicitly learn the difference. But that does not mean there is no difference! A native speaker who has received some training in Japanese grammar knows that a verb like 歩く is normally classified as an intransitive verb even though it takes を, and can explain the difference to you. Otherwise, any answer you get from a native speaker is likely to be almost random, no matter how intellectual they are. If I had been asked the same question 10 years ago, my answer would have been something like "I kind of feel を in 道を歩く might be special, but I'm not really sure. Is it transitive? I've never thought about its definition".
However, it's also important not to worry too much about the distinction between transitive and intransitive verbs. Ultimately, a transitive verb is nothing more than a verb that marks its argument with を. There are many verbs whose transitivity does not match between Japanese and English, and even within English, the distinction is sometimes blurry (e.g., "graduate college" / "graduate from college").
Finally, ～を伴う and ～に伴う are different. AがBを伴う means A is the primary element and B is the accompanying element. When AがBに伴う, A is the accompanying element to the primary element B. We say 王が従者を伴う and 従者が王に伴う but not 従者が王を伴う.

Unless there's something new in how younger speakers speak, "graduate a college" sounds a bit strange.  You could use "graduate" causatively, "The teacher graduated her".  But even that sounds strange unless it were a really special situation where, for example, a student needed only one more class to graduate, and despite actually failing the class the teacher gave them a passing grade.  I would suggest "to walk" as an intransitive verb in English which can be used transitively in some circumstance (like I walk my dog).

@A.Ellett How about "graduate collage"? I know this usage is still controversial but is listed in dictionaries.

I guess, nevermind my comment?  It seems to me somehow when saying "graduating" or "graduated" it doesn't sound quite as off as "graduate".  This is why I no longer teach English conversation.

To be honest, I totally get that natives don’t really think a whole lot about the grammar of their language especially children and to be honest I’m quite shock to find that I’ve been learning English transitive and intransitive the wrong way, https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BB%96%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E this link says that “I ate” is intransitive and I’ve always thought that eat and all of those variants to be only transitive but guess that proves me wrong. But at the end of the day I’m too don’t really think about a words transitivity in English either

But when it comes to learning other languages it because so important and especially with Japanese particles that don’t have an example form English we can kinda borrow from. Chinese on the other hand can actually help out when learning Japanese grammar. I feel like someone has posted it before but I feel like some essence of Japanese grammar comes from Chinese grammar.

Obviously not all of it can be taken but quite a few are can, like 込む　,て来る　,て行く　,の　,verb stem attaching to another verb makes a new verb and  even the omission of pronouns can be brought into Japanese grammar although Japanese grammar adds a few add ons to it. It sucks that I cant relay on Chinese this time to help me out.

"I am a native Japanese speaker myself, but you need to keep in mind that an average native Japanese speaker is terribly bad at explaining the grammar of their own language." I think this is equally true of native English speakers.

@JackyPlays In Latin and many other languages, distinction between transitive and intransitive is closer to Japanese, in that transitive or intransitive is property of given verb + its specific meaning, regardless of whether direct object is specified or not (see this). "edō" both in "Edō." (= "I eat.") and "Pānem edō." (= "I eat bread.") is transitive.

@JackyPlays Latin also has a special usage of intransitive verbs with nouns in accusative case (see this). There are also transitive verbs, which take 2 nouns in accusative case (see this). (Japanese particle を with transitive verbs is roughly equivalent to accusative case of Latin and other languages.)

@Arfrever I appreciate the help but I kinda need you help me simplify like the entire thing. I’ve tried to understand it but my brain just can’t comprehend what those pages are trying to tell. So I would appreciate it if you could make a separate comment about it while explaining it so that a kid could understand.  For some reason when it comes to long and complicated essays, my brain just flats out forget every word I’ve learned.

@JackyPlays Maybe you might be interested in some discussion in https://chat.stackexchange.com/ (either in new room or https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language)... (My first comment was response to your comment "I’m quite shock to find that I’ve been learning English transitive and intransitive the wrong way".)
